# how to load array response from ajax into array input textbox

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

We are sending data through Ajax call  and getting response as array. we want to loop that array and load into array input field. but data not loading into input.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="loadchild[]" id="loadchild[]" >
```

this textbox is in loop

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "asign.php",
    data: {plan_id: plan_id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (dta)
    {
        /*
         here  dta['insert_id'] is single value and 
         dta['child_ids'] are multiple values and i am getting as [1,2,3,4,5]     */

        for (var i = 0; i < dta['child_ids'].length; i++)
        {
            $("#loadchild[" + i + "]").val(dta['child_ids'][i]);
        }
    }
});
```

here i am getting as  [object Object] when asigning value to textbox

Please let me know how to pass array value one by one into

Comment: Through PHP you can't send array either you have to use json_encode or serialize that array then send to AJAX and use jQuery

Comment: `$("#loadchild["+i+"]")` This is not a valid jQuery selector, use `.eq(i)` instead

Comment: Plus, you can set id to some like this: `loadchild[]`

Comment: @Sunil Pachlangia OP is not sending the array to the server, he is sending another id, then wanting to return an array and output them in a bunch of  input

Comment: `$("#loadchild[]").eq(i).val(dta['child_ids'][i]); `  is this valid..?

Comment: i am getting  **Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #loadchild[]**

Comment: try my answer you have to escape the brackets like this $("#loadchild\\[\\]").eq(i).val(dta['child_ids'][i]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

1)you have to escape the brackets like this

```
for(var i=0;i<dta['child_ids'].length;i++)
  {
   //$("#loadchild["+i+"]").val(dta['child_ids'][i]);

   $("#loadchild\\[\\]").eq(i).val(dta['child_ids'][i]);

  }
```

Comment: glad to help you @venkyrao